# Object has no attribute 'lower'

Tags: python, class, inheritance, attributes

I'm working on a problem set from the MIT OpenCourseWare course (with no credit whatsoever) and came across this problem. I'm trying to create an RSS Feed filter.

I first created an object that defines the characteristics of a news story.

```
class NewsStory(object):
    def __init__(self, guid, title, subject, summary, link):
        self.guid = guid
        self.title = title
        self.subject = subject
        self.summary = summary
        self.link = link

    def get_guid(self):
        return self.guid

    def get_title(self):
        return self.title

    def get_subject(self):
        return self.subject

    def get_summary(self):
        return self.summary

    def get_link(self):
        return self.link
```

Next, this is the given class for a trigger.

```
class Trigger(object):
    def evaluate(self, story):
        """
        Returns True if an alert should be generated
        for the given news item, or False otherwise.
        """

        raise NotImplementedError
```

I then tried to create a subclass of Trigger, WordTrigger, to check if a word is in the text that I want to check.

```
class WordTrigger(Trigger):
    def __init__(self, word):
        self.word = word

    def is_word_in(self, text):
        word = self.word.lower()
        text = text.lower() 

        for p in string.punctuation:
            if p in text:
                text.replace(p, ' ')

        print self.word in text
```

To call `is_word_in`, I used another subclass of WordTrigger, TitleTrigger.

```
class TitleTrigger(WordTrigger):

    def evaluate(self, story):
        return self.is_word_in(story.get_title())
```

However, running the unit test for this gives me a new error (after editing the code):

`AssertionError: TitleTrigger failed to fire when the word appeared in the title`

Right now I'm not sure if the error is because of something wrong with conversion of lower to uppercase?

Here is the unit test that was given to me: (I included what I think are the relevant parts)

```
class ProblemSet5NewsStory(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        pass
    def testNewsStoryConstructor(self):
        add_potential_points(1)
        story = NewsStory('', '', '', '', '')
        add_points(1)

class ProblemSet5(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        class TrueTrigger:
            def evaluate(self, story): return True

        class FalseTrigger:
            def evaluate(self, story): return False

        self.tt = TrueTrigger()
        self.tt2 = TrueTrigger()
        self.ft = FalseTrigger()
        self.ft2 = FalseTrigger()

    def test1TitleTrigger(self):
        add_potential_points(5)
        koala     = NewsStory('', 'Koala bears are soft and cuddly', '', '', '')
        pillow    = NewsStory('', 'I prefer pillows that are soft.', '', '', '')
        soda      = NewsStory('', 'Soft drinks are great', '', '', '')
        pink      = NewsStory('', "Soft's the new pink!", '', '', '')
        football  = NewsStory('', '"Soft!" he exclaimed as he threw the football', '', '', '')
        microsoft = NewsStory('', 'Microsoft announced today that pillows are bad', '', '', '')
        nothing   = NewsStory('', 'Reuters reports something really boring', '', '' ,'')
        caps      = NewsStory('', 'soft things are soft', '', '', '')

        s1 = TitleTrigger('SOFT')
        s2  = TitleTrigger('soft')
        for trig in [s1, s2]:
            self.assertTrue(trig.evaluate(koala), "TitleTrigger failed to fire when the word appeared in the title")
            self.assertTrue(trig.evaluate(pillow), "TitleTrigger failed to fire when the word had punctuation on it")
            self.assertTrue(trig.evaluate(soda), "TitleTrigger failed to fire when the case was different")
            self.assertTrue(trig.evaluate(pink), "TitleTrigger failed to fire when the word had an apostrophe on it")
            self.assertTrue(trig.evaluate(football), "TitleTrigger failed to fire in the presence of lots of punctuation")
            self.assertTrue(trig.evaluate(caps), "TitleTrigger is case-sensitive and shouldn't be")

            self.assertFalse(trig.evaluate(microsoft), "TitleTrigger fired when the word was present, but not as its own word (e.g. 'soft' and 'Microsoft)'")
            self.assertFalse(trig.evaluate(nothing), "TitleTrigger fired when the word wasn't really present in the title")
```

I'm rather confused with how to make use of attributes in classes, especially when inheritance comes into play. Would really appreciate any help!

Comment: How are you calling the method `is_word_in`?

Comment: Maybe this is too obvious but You pass `NewsStory` object instead of string  into `evaluate` method.

Comment: you should be checking if self.word is in tocheck, I did the course a while back.

Comment: I've added in something I missed out earlier, the function `TitleTrigger` which calls `is_word_in`.

Comment: @oleg yes that seems to be the case but the instructions I received expressly said that that particular method, `evaluate` should not be changed, and they gave `def evaluate(self, story):`. Is it because I should define another `evaluate` method for the subclass `WordTrigger`? But would that then replace the `is_word_in` method?

Comment: why is `self.is_word_in(story)` in  evaluate?

Comment: Oh I realise that I should take out `self.is_word_in(story)` under `evaluate` and add an extra `evaluate` method under the `TitleTrigger` class. I actually that put that in previously because it shows me the error in `WordTrigger` instead of just returning a `NotImplementedError`.

Comment: what do you get when you just `print text` in is_word_in when running the tests?